# Investing for the 18 yr old college student

Tags: starting-out-investing

I am an 18 year old full-time college student. I only work during the summer months.  I am the beneficiary of an Inherited CD in the amount of $10,000.00. I would like to invest in something that has a better return than a CD or IRA. Any suggestions? I can tie this up for a long term if necessary.  Thank you

Comment: That profile pic makes me doubt the 18-year old college student qualification. :)

Comment: IRA can be invested many ways that meet differing risk profiles...

Answer (score 2):

If you are earning a salary, go for Roth IRA. You can contribute $5500 (2013 limits) every year . Once you open a account , let say Fidelity or Vanguard, you should invest based on risk appetite into some funds.

the advantage is that your money grows tax free and when you are 25- 30 years old and need money for down payment of house, you can pull the money out with out any penalty.

The gains you have made will continue to be in that account till the time your retire, growing every year.